# Closed form expression for sum of geometric number of normal variables?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose we have a random variable, $G$, distributed according to the geometric distribution with parameter $p$, i.e., one with PDF
\begin{equation}
P(G=k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}
\end{equation}
where $k \in [1,\infty) \cap \mathbb{N}$.

Now, suppose we have countably infinite, mutually independent normal distributions with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, denoted as $N_k$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now, let us create another random variable from these:
\begin{equation}
X = \sum_{k=1}^G N_k
\end{equation}

Is it possible to find a closed-form expression for the PDF, CDF, Expectation, and/or variance of this random variable $X$? I know that the expectation of $X$ is 0 if $\mu = 0$, obviously, as it is a sum of symmetric random variables, thus symmetric, thus has an expected value of 0.

I have tried a few different ways, and by "closed-form," I mean not using infinite sums, nor integrals, nor the like. At some point I had something with the polylogarithm, and functions like that are acceptable.

I'm pretty sure that the C.D.F. of this distribution is the sum:
\begin{equation}
F_X(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1} \Phi_k(x)
\end{equation}

Where $\Phi_k$ is the C.D.F. of the sum of $k$ independent normal variables, and I've tried normalizing and going from there, but I don't seem to see anyway to simplify it further from there, let alone find the PDF of this thing.

Comment: In your last equation it seems you've taken $p=\frac12$ instead of keeping it general? In the general case, wouldn't the mean simply be $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1}(k\mu) = \frac\mu p$?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: By the way, pairwise independence isn't a strong enough assumption (once $G\ge3$) for what I think you want; you should assume that all random variables are mutually independent.

Comment: Knowing the mean, I would now write the variance as $E(X^2)-(\frac\mu g)^2$, split into the various possible values of $G$, and use the fact that if $G=g$ then the variance is $g\sigma^2$ but is also equal to $E(X^2)-(g\mu)^2$, which allows you to calculate $E(X^2)$ conditioning on $g=G$.

Comment: Oop, yeah I DID mean mutually independent. Thanks for that, the mean and variance are definitely easier to calculate than I thought for this. PDF still seems... kind of like it's "that-thing-I-came-up-with-on-the-spot-so-I-doubt-it-has-a-closed-form-but-may-as-well-check-anyways"